# Samba user does not have folder read permission

Tags: permissions, samba

I have set up a special user for read only samba shares.  I set him up in Samba and as a system user.  I shared a couple of folders but that user cannot access them.  I know samba is working because I also shared them with the main user of the system which is an admin account and it works fine.

How can I allow this user to have read permissions on all the directories I want to share without changing anything for any other users of the system?  For example, I don't want to give him ownership of any of the files/directories.  Just ongoing recursive read access.  ongoing recursive is important.  If someone adds a file or directory, I still want him to automatically be able to read it.

Comment: samba itself probably does not have this fine a grain of access control. It depends on the file system on the server (ntfs vs ext4) and your samba configuration. In general, there are 3 sets of permissions, owner, group, and other. You can give the the samba use ro access via owner or group, but all the files need to be owned either by the samba user or the samba user's group. I think your best option is acl. There is one of many discussions on this issue here : here

Comment: ok maybe I am asking the wrong question then. If I am mounting a disk through fstab, what is the best way to give read access to a directory and all subdirectories on that disk to a user who is a system user and a samba user?

Comment: "it depends". what file system (ntfs != ext4) , permission by file ownership, group, or other Does the system/samba user own all the files ? if not, who does? what group?

Comment: It is a hfs volume with read only permission when it is mounted in fstab. I'm guessing it is owned by the user thats logged in when it is mounted - Admin.

Comment: post your fstab config, look at the ownership and permissions, and update your question. See also your mount options here : https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/hfsplus.txt . You have to decide if you want to manage permissions by owner (uid= ...) or group (gid = ...) and use umask to set permissions ...

Comment: fstab is pretty simple it just says /dev/sda /media/admin/Downloads1Mac hfsplus defaults 0 0

Comment: Use uid=xxx gid=yyy and umask=zzz in your mount options to set permissions. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#fat16_and_fat32 or post relevant information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

For the lazy, there's system-config-samba in the repository ( requires X though) through which you can configure your samba server a la windows point and click way.
Samba user by default are separate from linux users, unless you configure samba to use /etc/passwd for user management, and in which case your samba server will forward the underlying permissions.
Or you could let samba do its own thing, in which case you would have to map the samba user(s) to one or more linux user(s) and samba will write in the file system as the linux users for you.
Either ways, don't forget to sudo service smbd restart after you change something.

Comment: Thats what I did.  I created a system user called media.  I created a samba user called media.  I mounted a disk using fstab.  I add the directory on the disk using the gui and allowed both the media and the admin user to access the directory in samba.  The admin works.  The media user doesn't.  On windows and the mac it says permission to the directory is denied for the "media" user.

Comment: Did you set the permissions for the media user in samba in the guy for the folder? By default it has none. The samba permissions are in samba in which case are different from the unix perms.

Comment: no. Thats what I'm asking about.  I haven't set any permissions for the "media" user anywhere.  All I did was use the gui to share the directory for this user and the Admin user.  It works for the Admin user but it doesnt work for the "media"  All I want is for the media user to be able to read the files and folders on this disk via samba.